# Can't update a specific column in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sql-update, sequelize.js

I have a model. It is for the intermediate(pivot) table.

```
UserCars.init({
    carId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'UserCars',
  });
```

and here is my migration for this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('UserCars', {
      carId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Cars',
          key: 'id'
        },
      },
      userId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'id'
        },
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
    }, {
      uniqueKeys: {
        Items_unique: {
          fields: ['carId', 'userId']
        }
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('UserCars');
  }
};
```

And I'm doing this below to create/update it:

```
userCar = await UserCars.findOne({
    where: {
      carId: 10,
      userId: req.user.id,
    }
  });

  if(userCar) {
    userCar.userId = 20; // <--- This doesn't change
    userCar.title = 'some other thing'; // <--- This changes
    await userCar.save();
  } else {
    userCar = await UserCars.create({
        userId: 20,
        title: 'something'
    });
  }
```

The problem is, the title is being updated but the userId is not.

Comment: Can you show a generated `UPDATE` SQL query?

Comment: @Anatoly I expected it to be update, but it is insert into! and I don't know why.

Comment: If it is calling the INSERT, please check whether you are going inside `if` or `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

(I believe) this is due to constraints, you cannot use instance method to update FK value.

You need to use M-N association functions, or otherwise you could use raw SQL.

```js
const car = await Car.findByPk(10);
const user = await User.findByPk(newValue);

// This also takes care of deleting the old associations
await car.setUsers(user, { 
    through: {'title': 'new value'}
});
```

I hope the `upsert` function is implemented in the future.
ref: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11836